# Secure socket connection

Tags: java, sockets

I'm working on a school project with a server application that holds centralized data, and client applications that hold cached data that will be synchronized with sockets.
Everything is written in Java.

What is good practice?
How can I stop people from listening to my traffic? Or prevent people to understand what is said?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSL is the standard practice. See the `javax.net.ssl` package, and the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html). But this may be beyond the scope of your project or your abilities at this stage. Check with your instructor.

Answer (score 15):

You simply use [SSLSocketFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLSocketFactory) instead of SocketFactory for your client server application. That way, the communication between the two will be totally encrypted. You can secure your client server app in less than a day, if you know basic Java. Here's a [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/samples/index.html).

Comment: There is no evidence here that he is using `SocketFactory.`

Comment: Here's another tutorial: https://gpotter2.github.io/tutos/en/sslsockets